# setAttribute to img using an object

Tags: javascript

New to Javascript. This is a flashcard like program that is supposed to have images and then you guess the name. I'm using setAttribute but the images are not populating the page. Am I supposed to do a for loop for it to choose an image or do I simply just do what I've done? I need to use setAttribute but I'm stuck on why the images won't populate. Would really appreciate the help.

```js
function populateImages() {
  var newDiv = document.createElement('div');
  newDiv.setAttribute('class', 'frame');
  newDiv.setAttribute('src', personArray.url);
  newDiv.setAttribute('onclick', 'promptForName(this)');
  newDiv.setAttribute('onmouseover', 'styleIt(this)');
  newDiv.setAttribute('onmouseout', 'unStyleIt(this)');
  newDiv.setAttribute('id', '1');
  document.getElementById('pic-grid').appendChild(newDiv);
}
```

Here is my [JS Bin](https://jsbin.com/rekuvegixo/edit?html,output)

Comment: You have quotes around `personArray.url`. That would render it a string and not the object

Comment: If you want to see an image, use image tag:  <img src='blah.url' />

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get all the image icon you need to iterate over your array. And an array should be placed without quotes when you're setting the value. 
Change your div to `img` tag. I've done the corrections in your code, hope this helps.

```js
var currentId = "";
var x = 0;
var y = 0;

var personArray = [{
    firstname: "Ann",
    url: "http://www.tuktukdesign.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/person-icon.jpg"
  },
  {
    firstname: "Jane",
    url: "http://www.tuktukdesign.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/person-icon.jpg"
  },
  {
    firstname: "John",
    url: "http://www.tuktukdesign.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/person-icon.jpg"
  },
  {
    firstname: "Joe",
    url: "http://www.tuktukdesign.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/person-icon.jpg"
  }
];


function populateImages() {
  for (var i = 0; i < personArray.length; i++) {
    var newDiv = document.createElement('img');
    newDiv.setAttribute('class', 'frame');
    newDiv.setAttribute('src', personArray[i].url);
    newDiv.setAttribute('onclick', 'promptForName(this)');
    newDiv.setAttribute('onmouseover', 'styleIt(this)');
    newDiv.setAttribute('onmouseout', 'unStyleIt(this)');
    newDiv.setAttribute('id', '1');
    document.getElementById('pic-grid').appendChild(newDiv);
  }
}

function promptForName(element) {
  document.getElementById('response').value = "";
  document.getElementById('message').innerHTML = "";
  document.getElementById('prompt').style.display = 'block';
  currentId = element.id;
  x = element.offsetLeft;
  y = element.offsetTop;
  x = x + 20;
  y = y + 20;
  document.getElementById('prompt').style.position = "absolute";
  document.getElementById('prompt').style.top = y;
  document.getElementById('prompt').style.left = x;
  document.getElementById('response').focus();
}

function styleIt(element) {
  element.parentNode.style.backgroundColor = 'aqua';

}

function unStyleIt(element) {
  element.parentNode.style.backgroundColor = 'white';

}

function checkAnswer() {
  if (document.getElementById('response').value == personArray[currentId].firstname) {

    document.getElementById(currentId).className = "opClass";
    document.getElementById(currentId).removeAttribute("onclick");
    document.getElementById(currentId).removeAttribute("onmouseover");

    var divVar = document.createElement('div');
    divVar.setAttribute('id', currentId + 'name');
    document.getElementById('pic-grid').appendChild(divVar);
    var textNode = document.createTextNode(personArray[currentId].firstname);
    divVar.appendChild(textNode);
    document.getElementById(currentId + 'name').style.position = "absolute";
    document.getElementById(currentId + 'name').style.top = y;
    document.getElementById(currentId + 'name').style.left = x;

    document.getElementById('prompt').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById(currentId).parentNode.style.backgroundColor = 'white';
    document.getElementById('response').value = "";
    document.getElementById('message').innerHTML = "";
  } else {
    if (document.getElementById('message').innerHTML == "Wrong!") {
      document.getElementById('message').innerHTML = "Incorrect answer!"
    } else {
      document.getElementById('message').innerHTML = "Wrong!"
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

```css
body,
header {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 1em;
  background-color: silver;
}

.frame {
  padding: 25px;
  background-color: white;
  border: solid 1px black;
  display: inline-block;
}

#prompt {
  background-color: aqua;
  padding: 10px;
  display: none;
}

img {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.opClass {
  opacity: 0.4;
  filter: alpha(opacity=40);
  /* For IE8 and earlier */
  cursor: default;
}
```

```html
<body onload="populateImages()">
  <header>
    <h2>Class Flashcards</h2>
    <h3>Click on a student to guess their name</h3>
  </header>

  <div id="pic-grid">
  </div>

  <div id="prompt">
    What is this student's name?<br />
    <form onsubmit="return checkAnswer()">
      <input type="text" id="response" name="quizInput">
    </form>
    <div id="message"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```